# How far downwind of a Covid-19 emitter has a 1000-fold reduction in PPM?

Tags: aerodynamics

**How far downwind of a Covid-19 emitter has a 1000-fold reduction in PPM?**

Assuming that Covid-19 (0.12μm diameter) particles have the aerodynamic properties of a gas:

> Particles < 20 μm behave same as gas – Low settling velocity
> [http://home.engineering.iastate.edu/~leeuwen/CE%20524/Presentations/Dispersion_Handout.pdf](http://home.engineering.iastate.edu/%7Eleeuwen/CE%20524/Presentations/Dispersion_Handout.pdf)

How far would someone have to be downwind of a Covid-19 particle emitter for an at least 1000-fold reduction in PPM?

Answer (score 1):

I agree that it can be modeled as a gas. What you are looking for is called [Atmospheric Dispersion Modeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_dispersion_modeling). It is not a trivial calculation and requires lots of assumptions that change based on your situation. Just off the top of my head, some of the variables that come into pay are; emitter height above surface, detector height above the surface, surface roughness before emitter, surface roughness between emitter and detector, turbulence generated by emitter geometry, wind velocity, wind gust velocity (or variation in wind velocity, variance in wind direction, elevation, surface temperature relative to the air, barometric pressure, humidity, etc.

I have never done the estimate calculations or dispersion software modeling, and I'm sure there are several different approaches. These calculations are an important component in the EPA requirements for boiler stack height. A company what would like to install a new stack must verify that regulated gas emissions (NOx, SO2, CO etc) are below a certain ppm and the edge of the company's property.

The EPA recommends some [software on their website](https://www.epa.gov/scram/air-quality-dispersion-modeling-preferred-and-recommended-models); not sure how user-friendly it is, but probably much easier than starting from scratch.